# Modifying a re.split statement

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
s1 = AU,Singh Is "Ki,nng",2005,,,No,,,
```

I need to grab the title, `'Singh Is "Ki,nng"'` using a regular expression.

So far I can grab everything before the title --

```
>>> re.split(r',\d{4}',s2)[0]
'AU,Singh Is "Ki,nng"'
```

But it is also grabbing the territory, `AU`. How would I only grab the title here?

Comment: That looks like csv data, use csv module not regex.

Comment: It is not a valid csv file so I'm having to use regex instaead.

Comment: Hmm,, something like `re.search(r',(.*)?,(?=\d)', s1).group(1)` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this pattern and check against 2nd match

```
((?:[^,"]*"[^"]*"[^",]*)+|[^,]+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/208)

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you want from the output but this might do it

```
re.search(".+?,(.*?),\d+.*",s1).group(1)
```